# Running two php scripts on subfolders using WAMP and Apache

Tags: php, xml, apache, subdirectory, run-script

I'm trying to use php to do a few things:
I have a folder with 2650 subfolders... yeah, that many.
Currently, I have 2 scripts that process a xml on every subfolder, but I have to go manually into each folder, copy the xml to the wwwfolder, run both scripts (localhost/script1.php and localhost/script2.php) for each folder...
Is there a way to run both scripts on all of the subfolders?
This is the structure of the folders:

```
C:\wamp\www\Games\Game1\Meta-inf\details.xml
C:\wamp\www\Games\Game2\Meta-inf\details.xml
C:\wamp\www\Games\Game3\Meta-inf\details.xml
```

I would like to run a script, lets call it runner.php that does the following:

```
http://localhost/runner.php
cd Games
cd Game-1
cd Meta-inf
RUN script1.php
RUN script2.php
cd ..
cd ..
cd Game-2
cd Meta-inf
RUN script1.php
RUN script2.php
.
.
.
cd Game-2650
cd Meta-inf
RUN script1.php
RUN script2.php

EXIT foreach
Exit php
```

The problem here is I have no idea how to make a new php script that goes into the Gamex/Meta-inf/ and process the xml.
Each of the 2 scripts create a new file (1 excel and 1 txt) that files should be created on the /Game/Gamex/ folder... That should be modified on each script right?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Have you seen `glob`? You can pass it a pattern of `/Game-*/Meta-inf`, and get an array of all the directories that you could loop over.

Answer (score 1):

`glob()` will read each folder:

```
foreach(glob('FULL-PATH-TO/Gamex/Meta-inf/*') as $folder) {

  // process each folder in here...

}
```

If you wrap the existing code on your processing file in the `glob()` function it will do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to petebolduc and Tom Hart, I was able to figure it out.
I'll leave the full code here (I used an echo for testing purposes...)

THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!!

```
<?php
foreach(glob("C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Desktop\\Nuevos_Juegos\\SM\\*\\META-INF\\") as $folder)
{
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("$folder\\details.xml");
     $result = $xml->xpath('//name');
     foreach ($result as $node) 
     {
        if ( ($node['lang'] == 'en')  )
        {
            echo "$node" . "<br>";
        }

     } 
}
?>
```